# Jquery Initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a Jplayer on my website. The instructions say to use this code to initialise the plugin:

```
$('body').ttwVideoPlayer(myPlaylist, {options});
```

Where do I place this code?

The player loads correctly and the script works, but won't play the files in the playlist function.

Comment: It sounds like ttwVideoPlayer is loading correctly, so can you edit your post to include the contents of the `myPlaylist` function? The problem may be there.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually put all initialization code in a `$(document).ready` handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').ttwVideoPlayer(myPlaylist, {options});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted should be wrapped in an appropriate handler you're using like

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('body').ttwVideoPlayer(myPlaylist, {options});
     });
</script>
```

Don't forget to add an appropriate jQuery library for it to work.